# Column "xxx" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have the following two tables and entities:

```
Table A:

id | content | tag

Table B:
id | table_a_id | abc_date
```

I want for each distinct table A entity now what is the minimum abcDate in table B. For that, I wrote the following query:

```
 new JPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager)
      .select(tableB.tableA.id, tableA.abcDate.min())
      .from(tableB)
      .where(tableB.abcDate.between(start, end))
      .groupBy(tableB.tableA.id)
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        tuple -> tuple.get(0, TablA.class),
        tuple -> tuple.get(1, LocalDate.class)
      ));
```

However, I get the error that tableA.id has to be part of the groupBy clause. Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: min function is on tableA.abcDate, but you are grouping by tableB.tableA.id

Answer (score 0):

I have simplify your need.

```
SELECT a, MIN(b.abcDate)
FROM TableA a JOIN a.tableBs b
GROUP BY a.id
```

Join table a and table b then group by table a id and use the MIN function to get the minimum abcDate.